# Extract data from raster file (precipitation) and join to vector file database

Tags: qgis, raster

I am new in QGIS. I do have a raster file with precipitation data, and a vector data file that contains data on botanical collections (name of species, lon and lat). I want to extract the data of precipitation for each of the collection points, for each species There are 1200 data points. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In addition to explaining the situation, questions here are also expected to describe the steps you have taken, and what problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract a raster value for each point using the "Sample raster values" tool in the "Raster analysis" toolbox.

To get to the tool, select "Toolbox" from the "Processing" menu, then type "sample raster values" into the search box that appears.